# Countdown Timer for Racing Game

Tags: c++, opengl, timer, glut

I want to make a countdown timer for my racing game such as "3... 2... 1... GO!" I'm using GLUT, OpenGL, and C++. I was wondering what the most appropriate method to handle this in C++. clock()? glutTimerFunc()? I plan on having 4 textured polygons that shrink and fade one after the other.

Comment: You could code your own time manager using `glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);` That way you have real frame time correlation with what the user should see on their screen. Some code [here](http://mycodelog.com/2010/04/16/fps/). That's probably easier since you don't have to worry about performing really OS specific time calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *accumulate* time in your `update` loop.  Don't think in terms of "what time it is", instead, keep a `double` variable, called `timeTotal`.  Each frame, increment it by (`1.0/60.0`) (or whatever your fixed timestep is).  When the game starts, you can reset the timer, and your race start introduction would just go something like this:

```
void update()
{
  totalTime += 1.0/60.0 ; //increase time

  if( timeTotal > 1 )  // 3.
  else if( timeTotal > 2 )  // 2.
  else if( timeTotal > 3 )  // 1
  else { GO } // race on

}
```

You can refactor this in any number of ways, but this is the basic idea of how to trip time based events in a game system.